# Iterate over two iterators in parallel without using Python's zip function?

Tags: python, iterator, iteration, generator

In python, the idiomatic way of iterating over to iterators in parallel is to use the "zip" function.

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 31 2018, 19:45:04) [GCC] on linux
>>> it1 = range(0,5)
>>> it2 = range(3,10)
>>> for x1, x2 in zip(it1, it2): print('', x1, x2, sep='\t')
... 
        0       3
        1       4
        2       5
        3       6
        4       7
>>> it1 = range(0,5)
>>> it2 = range(3,10)
>>> [ 100*x1 + x2 for x1,x2 in zip(it1,it2) ]
[3, 104, 205, 306, 407]
```

However, I dislike the pattern here, which decouples the assignment of items to names from the order of items in the zipped iterable: In more complex examples one might easily produce an error such as

```
for apple1, apple2, orange in zip(apples, oranges, more_apples): ...
```

Hence I was wondering if there is a pattern, that allows something akin to

```
for apple1 in apples,\
    apple2 in oranges,\
    orange in more_apples: ...
```

where such mistakes would be more obvious.

For list comprehension a similar-looking syntax exists, but corresponds to `itertools.product()` rather than `zip()`.

Comment: As a comment unrelated to the question: lines like `it1 = range(0,5)` are not necessary more than once, as they are not generators, and don't get exhausted. As for your question, a workaround would be to use *enumerate* on the 1st list, and get elements from the other lists via index.

Comment: I guess using `for i in range(len(apples)): apples[i], oranges[i], ...` would be one of alternatives, but dealing with different lengths wouldn't be as elegant as using `zip`.

Comment: @Chris It would also not work, if apples, oranges, are iterators (cannot be indexed) and the expected number of elements makes wrapping into an indexable container unviable.

Comment: When downvoting, please comment on *why*.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
[100 * it1[i] + it2[i] for i in range(min(len(it1), len(it2)))]
```

Comment: This puts even more distance between the element and the iteratable (which OP tries to minimize)

Comment: Actually it would work in the specific toy example, but when it1, it2 are not bound to names, or are general iterators (cannot be indexed), it breaks down.

Comment: @DeepSpace From what I understood from the question, his problem was that he could get confused in the order of the items inside and outside the `zip` which would cause mistakes, and in my solution there is no meaning to the order of iterables inside the `range(min(len...` function

Answer (score 0):

If your entries are lists with equal length, you could accomplish what you wanted with a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

With `zip`, you would do something like this:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b','c']
l2 = ['A','B','C']

result = [e1+' '+e2 for e1, e2 in zip(l1, l2)]
print(result)
```

and get

```
['a A', 'b B', 'c C']
```

Alternatively, you could combine both lists into a `pd.DataFrame`, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'l1': l1, 'l2':l2})
```

(note that you still have to use one more name per list, but the line does have `'l1'` right next to `l1`, unlike the `zip` usage).

Now, you could iterate over the rows in the dataframe (or do other things...) simply with

```
result = [row['l1']+' '+row['l2'] for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Which would give the same result.

Comment: Some major downsides: *(a) Verbosity.* But that can be improved to `[ f'{r.l1} {r.l2}' for _, r in pandas.DataFrame({'l1': l1, 'l2': l2}).iterrows() ]`. *(b) The dependency.* Adding a major dependency like pandas only for the sake of abusing it, doesn't strike me as a good idea. *(c) Different semantics.* The iterators are required to have the *same length* and that length is required to be *finite*. Furthermore that result must be small enough for the table to fit into memory.

Comment: The idea is interesting though: What I want can be achieved with a custom "zip" function returning some kind of record or `collections.namedtuple`, such that it can be used as `[ f(t.l1, t.l2) for t in namedzip(l1=iter1, l2=iter2)]`. I would still prefer, if that were supported by the builtin zip function though for the sake of code-readability.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an abuse (aligning two arrays together is exactly what a dataframe is for), and I don't think that inlining a dataframe definition is good for readability, but the big issue is indeed the semantics - same length, finite length, all those problems.

Comment: it would definitely be better all-round if this was supported by the built-in zip function; I just don't think that there's such a solution.